# How to connect to MSSQL from windows and ubuntu, without writing two sets of code?

Tags: php, sql-server

My production machine is ubuntu, and my dev machine is windows.  If I want to connect to a MSSQL server, from both ubuntu and windows, how do I do it?  I'm able to use microsoft's library to connect to the database from my dev machine, but this wouldn't work on the ubuntu machine, correct?

Comment: As long as MSSQL is configured to allow TCP connections, you can use the same DSN for both machines (assuming there's no firewalls and whatnot in the way).

Comment: Oh no, not the DSN.  I am talking about inserts, updates and deletes.  Looks like there is a library from microsoft, for windows, and FreeTDS for connecting to linux.  Until PHP 5.3, we could simply use php_mssql.dll, it worked on both windows and linux.  Now that is gone, what is the preferred way to connect to both, without writing two sets of inserts etc?

Comment: PHP has an mssql driver. There'd be NO difference in how you write the queries. Only the DSN matters. once you're connected to the DB, regardless of what OS/platform you're on, the queries will work.

Comment: Ok.  Are you talking about php_mssql.dll?  That seems to have been dropped in PHP 5.3.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx. Regardless of which driver you end up using, it'd still be the usual mssql_*() functions to actually USE the database.

Comment: I am not sure if that is correct.  For example, if you look at this page, http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/whitepaper-accessing-sql-server-databases-from-php.aspx it is using sqlsrv_* functions, not mssql_*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3411/discussion-between-user187809-and-marc-b)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PDO SQL Server driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx) from Microsoft when on Windows and the [PDO DLIB](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) when on Linux. Other than connecting, you're code will be the same.

If you're unable to use either of those drivers, you'll have to look into [PHP ODBC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php).